# How to copy from a file to an array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have to read an array from a file and the fact i that's the last column is just not being copied. The size of the array and it content is in the file. Here is the code (only the part where the problem is):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){ 
char **laberinto;
char aux;
fent = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if
 fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't open.\n");
else
{
 laberinto = (char **) calloc(columnas, sizeof(char *));
 for (i = 0; (NULL != laberinto) && (i < columnas); i++)
  {
      laberinto[i] = (char *) calloc(filas, sizeof(char));
      if (NULL == laberinto[i])
       {
        for ( j = i - 1; j >= 0; j-- )
          free(laberinto[j]); 
        free(laberinto);
        laberinto = NULL;
       }
  }
 for(i = 0, j = 0; i < filas+1; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < columnas+1; j++)
      {
        if(!feof(fent))
          {
            aux = fgetc(fent);
            if(aux == '\n')
            aux = 0;
           }}
```

`Edit 1(full code) it generates a core by the way:`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"encruta1.h"//Just funcion definitions(not used yet)
#define ERRORCOMANDO "ERROR: linea de comandos incorrecta. Utilice:\n" 
#define ERRORCOMAND2 "leelabfich fichero_de_entrada columna_inicio fila_inicio\n"
//Both are error messages

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char **laberinto;
  char aux;
  int i = 0;//Indice para imprimir la tabla
  int j = 0;//Indice para imprimir la tabla
  int columnas = 0;
  int filas = 0;
  int flag1;//Para saber si fscanf ha funcionado bien
  FILE *fent;

  //Si son cuatro argumentos es correcto
  if(argc == 4)
   {
    //Apertura de archivo
    fent = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fent == NULL)
     fprintf(stderr,"No se puede abrir el fichero de entrada.\n");
    else
    {
     flag1 = fscanf(fent,"%d%d", &columnas, &filas);
     if(flag1 == 2)
     {
      if(filas < 0 || columnas < 0)
       fprintf(stderr,"Las dimensiones han de ser dos numeros enteros.\n");
      else
       {
       //Reserva de memoria   
       laberinto = (char **) calloc(columnas, sizeof(char *));
       for (i = 0; (NULL != laberinto) && (i < columnas); i++)
        {
          laberinto[i] = (char *) calloc(filas, sizeof(char));
          if (NULL == laberinto[i])
          {
        for ( j = i - 1; j >= 0; j-- )
          free(laberinto[j]); 
        free(laberinto);
        laberinto = NULL;
          }
        }

      //Pasamos el laberinto del archivo a la tabla

      for(i = 0, j = 0; i < filas+1; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < columnas+1; j++)
          {
        if(!feof(fent))
          {
            aux = fgetc(fent);
            if(aux == '\n')
              aux = 0;
            else
              laberinto[i][j] = aux;
          }
          }

      for(i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        {
          for(j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
        {//Eliminamos los intentos fallidos
          if(laberinto[i][j] == 'o')//Just ignore the o
            laberinto[i][j] = '.';
          printf("%c", laberinto[i][j]);
        }
          printf("\n");
        }
      //Sustituir por donde se libere memoria abajo
      for(i = 0; i < columnas+1; i++)
        free(laberinto[i]);
      laberinto = NULL;
```

Comment: Your code example does not compile.  Is this the actual code you have been using?  `fent`, `columnas`, `i`, `filas`, `j`, ... are all undefined.  It would also be good to know the what the file format/contents are.

Comment: No it is just a short version of it. I'll edit to put the full code

Comment: Please, only the parts relevant to make it compile and illustrate your problem.  _[sscce](http://sscce.org/)_

Comment: Don't cast `calloc()` to `char **` it's not necessary.

Comment: Sorry first time posting. I 've been about one hour right now looking and thinking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are far better served using *line-oriented* input to read all lines in a file into a dynamically allocated array. The *line-oriented* functions available in the standard library are `fgets` and `getline`.

In this case, where you do not know what the maximum number of characters in each line will be, you are better served using `getline` to read each line as `getline` will dynamically allocate a line buffer of sufficient size for you.

If you use `fgets` (which is fine), you would have to add code to check for a *short* or *incomplete* read of each line and `realloc` and `strcat` the line until a complete read takes place. `getline` just makes life simpler here.

Your basic scheme is to declare a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* (i.e. a *double-pointer*), allocate a reasonable number of pointers to handle the file, if you reach the initial limit, `realloc` `2X` the number of current pointers and continue.

When done, free the allocated lines, then free the array. A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NMAX 128    /* initial number of pointers */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **array = NULL;            /* array to hold lines read         */
    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* initial ln size, getline decides */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* array index counter              */
    size_t nmax = NMAX;             /* check for reallocation           */
    size_t i = 0;                   /* general loop variable            */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin; /* open stream  */

    if (!fp)  {       /* validate stream open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s',\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate NMAX pointers to char* */
    if (!(array = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line from fp  */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

        array[idx++] = strdup (ln); /* allocate/copy ln to array        */

        if (idx == nmax) {          /* if idx reaches nmax, reallocate  */
            char **tmp = realloc (array, nmax * 2 * sizeof *tmp);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted.\n");
                break;
            }
            array = tmp;    /* set new pointers NULL */
            memset (array + nmax, 0, nmax * sizeof tmp);
            nmax *= 2;
        }
    }

    if (ln) free (ln);              /* free memory allocated by getline */
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close open file if not default   */

    /* print array */
    printf ("\n lines read from '%s'\n\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("   line[%3zu]  %s\n", i, array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        free (array[i]);    /* free each line */
    free (array);           /* free pointers  */

    return 0;
}
```

Use a memory error checker (like `valgrind` on Linux) to confirm correct use of the memory and that all memory is properly freed when no longer needed. Look it over and let me know if you have additional questions.

**Numeric Array**

For numeric arrays, you approach is exactly the same. However, instead of storing the `ln` in an array of pointers to char, you simply parse the line as required using `sscanf` or preferrably `strtol`, etc... The changes required are minimal. e.g.:

```
...
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
...
long *array = NULL;             /* pointer to long                  */
int base = argc > 2 ? atoi (argv[2]) : 10; /* base (default: 10)    */
...
```

your read loop then looks like:

```
/* read each line from file - separate into array       */
while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
{
    char *p = ln;      /* pointer to ln read by getline */
    char *ep = NULL;   /* endpointer for strtol         */

    while (errno == 0)
    {   /* parse/convert each number in line into array */
        array[idx++] = xstrtol (p, &ep, base);

        if (idx == nmax)        /* check NMAX / realloc */
            array = realloc_long (array, &nmax);

        /* skip delimiters/move pointer to next digit   */
        while (*ep && *ep != '-' && (*ep < '0' || *ep > '9')) ep++;
        if (*ep)
            p = ep;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

The helper functions to validate the conversions to `long` and `realloc` could be written as:

```
/* reallocate long pointer memory */
long *realloc_long (long *lp, unsigned long *n)
{
    long *tmp = realloc (lp, 2 * *n * sizeof *lp);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: reallocation failed.\n", __func__);
        // return NULL;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    lp = tmp;
    memset (lp + *n, 0, *n * sizeof *lp); /* memset new ptrs 0 */
    *n *= 2;

    return lp;
}
```

**note:** you can adjust whether to return `NULL` or `exit` on memory exhaustion to fit your needs. For the conversion, you can use simple error checking with `strtol` as shown below.

```
/* simple strtol wrapper with error checking */
long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base)
{
    errno = 0;

    long tmp = strtol (p, ep, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == LONG_MIN || tmp == LONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtol");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*ep == p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

I have place a full example of how to read a file into a dynamically allocated 2D array of long at pastbin: [**C - read file into dynamically allocated 2D array**](http://pastebin.com/yM2tUvH5)