# Matrix read from a file in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have two matrices in a file in the following format:

```
17.053 24 1 8 15
23 5 7 14 16
4 6 13 20 22
10 12 19 21 3
11 18 25 2 9

1 3 1 4
0 5 0 4
2 1 2 4
```

These are just two arbritary matrices and they are always seperated by an empty line. They can be of any size and shape. I have the following code that reads the two matrices and finds out the number of rows and columns of each. How do I go about inputting these into the two matrices defined as `mat_A` and `mat_B`?

I have tried fscanf but I print out only 0s. How do I read in the values to my two 2d arrays that are supposed to hold them?

```
int main(void)
{

    int space_count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;;
    FILE *fp;
    fp =  fopen("inputformat", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("File not read!");
    int NumCols_first, NumCols_second, NumRows_first, NumRows_second;
    int issecondmatrix = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    double **mat_A = (double **) malloc(NumRows_first * sizeof(double*));
    for(i=0; i<NumRows_first; i++)
        mat_A[i] = (double *) malloc(NumCols_first * sizeof(double));

    double **mat_B = (double **) malloc(NumRows_second * sizeof(double*));
    for(i=0; i<NumRows_second; i++)
        mat_B[i] = (double *) malloc(NumCols_second * sizeof(double));

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
        printf("Line is of length : %u \n", read);
        printf("Line is:%s\n", line);
        for(i=0; i<read; i++){
            printf("%c\n", line[i]);
            if(line[i] == ' ')
                space_count++;
            if(read == 1){
                printf("Next matrix gonna start after this\n"); 
                NumRows_first = j;
                issecondmatrix = 1;
                j = 0;
            }   
        }
        if(j==1 & issecondmatrix == 0)
            NumCols_first = space_count + 1;
        if(j==1 & issecondmatrix == 1)
            NumCols_second = space_count + 1; 
        space_count = 0;
        j++;
    }
    NumRows_second = j - 1;
    printf("num of columns in first matrix is %d\n", NumCols_first);
    printf("number of rows in first matrix is %d\n", NumRows_first);
    printf("num of columns in second matrix is %d\n", NumCols_second);
    printf("num of rows in second matrix is %d\n", NumRows_second);
    for(i=0; i<NumRows_first)
    {
    for(j=0; j<NumCols_first; j++)
    {
        if(!(fscanf(fp, "%lf", &mat_A[i][j]))
            break;
        printf("%lf", mat_A[i][j]);
    }
}
enter code here




    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `fscanf()` should work. How are you calling it? I couldn't find anything in your code. By the way: `if(j==1 & issecondmatrix == 0)` -- you want `&&`, not `&` in there. Same for the next line.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize that part got left out. I've updated it. I'm not too sure on how to read the second matrix. The first one I tried like this and I am getting only zeros

Comment: You are on the right track. You can simply test `if (*line = '\n')` to catch the newline and switch between filling `mat_A` and `mat_B`. I would encourage walking down `line` with `strtod` performing conversions of all values. There are many duplicates, I'll try and find one.

Comment: But why do I get 0's when I try to print mat_A?

Comment: Since you have already read past it with `getline`, you need to `rewind()` before reading with `fscanf` (though I encourage you to use `strtod` to convert all values to `double`)

Comment: @sam - you will find [How to copy from a file to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688545/how-to-copy-from-a-file-to-an-array/34689197?r=SearchResults&s=12|46.7476#34689197) helpful, but I'm still looking for a duplicate (that is for char arrays).

Comment: Okay I got mat_A right by using rewind(fp). I'm still a little confused on how to approach reading the second matrix after the newline.

Comment: You call `malloc()` before calculating the number of rows and columns.  You either need to continuously `realloc()` as the array grows, or scan through the file first to calculate the rows/columns and again to load the values

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, in order to test *line == '\n', I would have to use the getline command right? Or can I do it with the fscanf itself?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I got it. I just had to continue scanning with fscanf and it read out B into mat_B. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure you are running your code through a memory/error check (like `valgrind` on Linux) to make sure you have no allocation errors and that you free all memory you allocate. Also, rather than `mat_A` and `mat_B`, you should create a struct (e.g. `struct mtrx { double **matrix, size_t row, col };` so you can declare an array of pointers to struct and loop over your file filling matrices as you go using an index rather than separate `_A` and `_B` variables. Also you should never read a file twice, (file I/O is SLOW). Read a line/convert all `doubles` in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your example code, the obvious one is the matrix size is not initiated before memory allocation. You either first scan through the file to find the size of matrix and allocate memory, then scan through the 2nd time to fill the matrix; or you can allocate a big enough memory first, then fill it while scan through the file. Here is a working example with many error checking ignored (for shorter code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse_empty(char *word)
{
    for(; *word!='\0'; word++)
        if(!isspace(*word))
            break;
    return (*word=='\0');
}

int parse_line(char *line, float *data, int max)
{
    int n=0; char *p=line, *left=line;
    while((p=strchr(left, ' '))!=NULL) {
        *p='\0';
        if((n<max) && (!parse_empty(left))) {
            data[n] = atof(left);
            n++;
        }
        left = p+1;
    }
    if(!parse_empty(left)) {
        data[n] = atof(left);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

#define MAX_LINESZ 128
void parse_matrix(FILE *fp, float *data, int max, int *mm, int *nn)
{
    int m=0, n=0; char *line; size_t len=MAX_LINESZ;
    line = malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    while(getline(&line, &len, fp)!=-1) {
        if(parse_empty(line))
            break;
        n = parse_line(line, data, max);
        data = data+n;
        max  = max-n;
        m++;
    }
    free(line);
    *mm=m; *nn=n;
}

//data must be malloc/calloc memory!
float **matrix_realloc(float *data, int max, int m, int n)
{
    assert(max>=m*n);
    float **mat;
    mat = malloc(m*sizeof(float*));
    mat[0] = realloc(data, m*n*sizeof(float));
    for(int i=1; i<m; i++)
        mat[i] = mat[i-1]+n;
    return mat;
}
void matrix_free(float **matrix)
{
    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);
}

#define MAX_MATRIX (8*8)
int main()
{
    float *data1, *data2;
    int m1, m2, n1, n2;

    FILE *fp = fopen("t.dat", "r");
    data1 = malloc(MAX_MATRIX*sizeof(float));
    data2 = malloc(MAX_MATRIX*sizeof(float));
    parse_matrix(fp, data1, MAX_MATRIX, &m1, &n1);
    parse_matrix(fp, data2, MAX_MATRIX, &m2, &n2);

    float **mat1 = matrix_realloc(data1, MAX_MATRIX, m1, n1);
    float **mat2 = matrix_realloc(data2, MAX_MATRIX, m2, n2);
    for(int i=0; i<m1; i++) {
        printf("1>");
        for(int j=0; j<n1; j++) 
            printf(" %8.2f", mat1[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m2; i++) {
        printf("2>");
        for(int j=0; j<n2; j++) 
            printf(" %8.2f", mat2[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    matrix_free(mat1);
    matrix_free(mat2);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```